# Get certain value from JSON string

Tags: c#, json, api, json.net

I have the following code which gets me the entire JSON string; however, I want to get just the `cashprice` for this.

```
string url = "http://ondemand.websol.barchart.com/getGrainBids.json?apikey=12345&location=54943&commodityName=Corn%20(%232%20Yellow)&bidsPerCom=2";

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
{
    using (StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
    {
        string json = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
        string data = JObject.Parse(json)["bids/price"].ToString();
        Label1.Text = data;
    }
}
```

The part I have commented out is what I want to work but each time I try that it returns just a null value.  This is the JSON string that shows when the reader runs:

```
{
  "status": {
    "code": 200,
    "message": "Success."
  },
  "results": [
    {
      "bids": [
        {
          "id": "19699878",
          "commodity": "CORN",
          "symbol": "ZCH19",
          "delivery_start": "2019-03-01 00:00:00",
          "delivery_end": "2019-03-31 23:59:59",
          "basis": "-35.00",
          "notes": null,
          "active": true,
          "sym_root": "ZC",
          "commodity_id": "119555",
          "customer_commodity_id": "5813",
          "commodity_display_name": "Corn (#2 Yellow)",
          "unitvalue": 1,
          "unitweight": 56,
          "deliveryMonth": "Mar19",
          "deliveryYear": "2019",
          "basismonth": "Mar 2019",
          "timestamp": 1544543949,
          "as_of": "09:59",
          "price": "3.48",
          "pricecwt": "6.205357",
          "basiscwt": -62.5,
          "pricetonne": "136.804545",
          "basistonne": -1377.8875,
          "change": "-0.015",
          "rawchange": -0.015,
          "pctchange": "-0.43",
          "cashprice": "3.48",
          "cashpricetonne": "136.804545",
          "delivery_sort": "2019-03-01 00:00:00",
          "delivery_start_raw": "2019-03-01 00:00:00",
          "delivery_end_raw": "2019-03-31 23:59:59",
          "basisSymbol": "ZCBH19-54943-5813.CM",
          "cashPriceSymbol": "ZCPH19-54943-5813.CM"
        },
        {
          "id": "14938531",
          "commodity": "CORN",
          "symbol": "ZCZ19",
          "delivery_start": "2019-12-01 00:00:00",
          "delivery_end": "2019-12-31 23:59:59",
          "basis": "-45.00",
          "notes": null,
          "active": true,
          "sym_root": "ZC",
          "commodity_id": "119555",
          "customer_commodity_id": "5813",
          "commodity_display_name": "Corn (#2 Yellow)",
          "unitvalue": 1,
          "unitweight": 56,
          "deliveryMonth": "Dec19",
          "deliveryYear": "2019",
          "basismonth": "Dec 2019",
          "timestamp": 1544543947,
          "as_of": "09:59",
          "price": "3.56",
          "pricecwt": "6.361607",
          "basiscwt": -80.3571428571,
          "pricetonne": "140.249263",
          "basistonne": -1771.56964286,
          "change": "-0.01",
          "rawchange": -0.01,
          "pctchange": "-0.28",
          "cashprice": "3.56",
          "cashpricetonne": "140.249263",
          "delivery_sort": "2019-12-01 00:00:00",
          "delivery_start_raw": "2019-12-01 00:00:00",
          "delivery_end_raw": "2019-12-31 23:59:59",
          "basisSymbol": "ZCBZ19-54943-5813.CM",
          "cashPriceSymbol": "ZCPZ19-54943-5813.CM"
        }
      ],
      "distance": null,
      "company": "Ag Partners",
      "locationId": 54943,
      "location": "Brown/Sab/Rulo/WC",
      "facility_type": "Country Elevator",
      "address": "2750 Acorn Rd",
      "city": "Sabetha",
      "state": "KS",
      "lng": -95.786193,
      "lat": 39.9061537,
      "phone": "785-284-2185",
      "url": "www.agpartnerscoop.com",
      "zip": "66534",
      "county": "Nemaha County",
      "basisTimestamp": "2018-12-11T09:02:48-06:00"
    }
  ]
}
```

Any suggestions how to get the 3.48 show correctly? I'm sure it's something small I'm missing.

Comment: It's returning `null` because you're looking for the price the wrong way. Instead of doing this .Parse(json)["bids/price"], you should do .Parse(json)["bids"]["price"].. Try that out and let me know.

Comment: @CarlosParra that also returned null... do I need to add ["results"] in front of both of those?

Comment: yup, missed that out. results is where "bids" belongs to.

Comment: There are multiple bids.  Are you wanting to get just the `cashprice` for the first one, or for all of them?

Comment: @BrianRogers just the first one

Comment: @CarlosParra got it to come back with a different error at "at Accessed JArray values with invalid key value: "bids". Int32 array index expected.'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple bids in the JSON.  If you just want to get the first one, you can use [`SelectToken`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_SelectToken.htm) and supply a path like this:

```
JObject jo = JObject.Parse(json);
string cashPrice = (string)jo.SelectToken("results[0].bids[0].cashprice");
Label1.Text = cashPrice;
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/rUklUq

If you want to get prices for all bids, you can use [`SelectTokens`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_SelectTokens.htm) and use a wildcard like this:

```
JObject jo = JObject.Parse(json);

List<string> allPrices = jo.SelectTokens("results[0].bids[*].cashprice")
                           .Values<string>()
                           .ToList();
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/lGbJEe

Comment: Awesome! That did it!.  So if I wanted to get the second I would change do [1] I assume?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  Or you can get them both in one fell swoop using SelectTokens and a wildcard.  I've updated my answer to demonstrate that as well.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the Json string into a Json Object and get the results array.

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
```

Once you have the Json Object you need to get the `results[]` and loop through it to get the `Bids[]` and in there you can get `cashprice`.

Answer (score 1):

For things like this we like to use JsonPaths. Here is our go to references if you want to try that way. http://jsonpath.com/ and https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/index.html#e2

```
  var data = JObject.Parse(json).SelectTokens("$.results[*].bids[*].price");
  var result = data;
```

Comment: Tried this and this is what was showing for result 
"Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JsonPath.FieldFilter+d__4"

Answer (score 0):

Brian had the perfect answer:

```
JObject jo = JObject.Parse(json);
string cashPrice = (string)jo.SelectToken("results[0].bids[0].cashprice");
Label1.Text = cashPrice;
```